# Point doubling with only one coordinate

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

In many source codes that implement ECDH, there is a function that multiplies the base point of that curve with a constant. This function usually takes as arguments the constant and just one coordinate of the point.  All formulas for multiplying a point on an elliptic curve with a constant involves both coordinates of that point. Can anybody explain how those functions do their job?

For example, [look here](https://github.com/WireGuard/WireGuard/blob/master/src/crypto/zinc/curve25519/curve25519-fiat32.c).

The function curve25519_generic multiplies the base point of curve25519 with the scalar. A point on curve25519 has both coordinates on 32 bytes, but the function takes just the x as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Montgomery Powering Ladder](https://cr.yp.to/bib/2003/joye-ladder.pdf) for computing the scalar product of a point P on an elliptic curve (or in every other [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group)) only needs the x-coordinate of P.

It is used widely since it is believed to be secure against side channel attacks, which is not true in all cases-- [for example, see this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4599562).

For further details concerning the Montgomery Powering Ladder, see the subsection "Montgomery's ladder technique" [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

To compute $d\cdot P, P\in E(K)$ we have the following formulas which are used in MPL:

Let $P_{1}, P_{2}, P_{3}, P'_{3} \in E(K): y^{2} = x^{3} + Ax + B$

$P_{3} = P_{1} + P_{2}$

$P'_{3} = P_{1} - P_{2} = \left(x'_{3}, y'_{3}\right)$

$x_{3} = \dfrac{2\left(x_{1} + x_{2}\right)\left(x_{1}x_{2} + A\right) + 4B}{\left(x_{1} - x_{2}\right)^{2}} - x'_{3}$

As you see, the y-coordinate of P is not needed in this computation.

I hope my answer satisfies your need!

Comment: Can you point me to the source of these formulas? Thx

Comment: These formulars are out of the paper 'Improved Elliptic Curve Multiplication Methods Resistant against Side Channel Attacks' by Tetsuya Izu, Bodo Möller and Tsuyoshi Takagi.  

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-36231-2_24